# How to consume an external API in Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, resttemplate

I want to consume Json from an API. the API looks like this:

```
{
  "allStudents": [
    {
      "fname": "Jack",
      "age": 22,
      "courses": {
        "name": "AI"
      }
    },
    {
     ..
    },
    ..
  ]
}
```

I am struggling with the fact that all the data are in an array.

I created a `Student Class`

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private List<Course> courses;
}
```

with all the getters and setters.

How to consume data from this API ?

I tried the following :

```
Student[] students= restTemplate.getForObject(url, Student[].class);
```

But this is not working and giving an error
`JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of Student out of START_OBJECT token`

Comment: Here you have to parse a object that contains a list of students, not a single student as you are doing.

Comment: Write a container class that has a `Student[] allStudents` field and map to that object.

Comment: @MattiaRighetti I am trying to parse an array of students, it's not possible ?

Comment: It is not correct in your case, you have to create a class that has a `Student[]` field called `allStudents`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the outer object.

Add another class

```
public class StudentList {
  List<Student> allStudents;
}
```

and then use `.getForObject(url, StudentList.class);`

Answer (score 2):

You need a

```
class ResultContainer {
    Student[] allStudents;
}
```

and then parse the result as

```
Student[] students = restTemplate.getForObject(url, ResultContainer.class).allStudents;
```